# How to filter post type title properly on post type archive?

Tags: wordpress, filter, seo, title, custom-post-type

I have used this code to filter `$title` of a custom post type, and it works perfectly fine when there are search results  e.g A query for Mercedes Benz cars for sale in Paris would show a `$title` like this `Mercedes Benz used cars for sale in Paris on Sitename`

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title');
function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) 
{
  if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' )
  {
    $location = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_location');
    $model = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_model');
    $title = $model[0]->name . 'used cars for sale in' . $location[0]->name .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');
  }
  return $title;
}
```

But then again, when there aren’t any search results, the code returns a single term title e.g A query for Mercedes Benz cars for sale in Paris would show a `$title` like this `Mercedes Benz archives – Sitename`
I need this to return filtered `$title` for all search queries, because I have a sitemap pulling these links from the custom post type. So I obviously need this to function for SEO reasons.

I’ve been struggling with this for some time now.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do you not just need an else statement?

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title');

function vehicle_listing_title( $title ){

   if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' ){
      $location = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_location');
      $model = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_model');
      $title = $model[0]->name . 'used cars for sale in' . $location[0]->name .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');
  }else{
     $title = 'Sorry there are no' . $model[0]->name . 'used cars for sale in' . $location[0]->name .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');
  }

return $title;
}
```

If this doesn't work maybe this would:

```
elseif(/*there are no results or post_count = 0 */)
```

Sorry about the vague elseif but I'm not sure how you are getting the results, if it's a search or a CPT archive.